# BASH Problems saving pipe awk to variable and then executing it by calling the variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

Good afternoon everyone,

I have the following problem with BASH:

If I run the following code:

```
var_echo="echo "
var_text="uno dos tres"
var_pipe=" | awk '{print \$2}' "
EJECUTAR=$($var_echo $var_text $var_pipe )
echo "$EJECUTAR"
```

#Result:

```
uno dos tres | awk '{print $2}'
```

It only shows me the characters stored in the variables without the "echo", but if I execute it in the following way it works

```
var_echo="echo "
var_text="uno dos tres"
EJECUTAR=$($var_echo $var_text | awk '{print $2}' )
echo "$EJECUTAR"
```

#Result:

```
dos
```

How can I make the pipe with awk work for me from the variable, I don't get the error.

From already thank you very much.

Greetings.

I can't understand why it takes the variable and shows it as text characters and doesn't execute the pipe with awk

Comment: Please take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: And like @shelter says usually, good luck

Comment: Hello everyone, I leave the link with the example.

thanks for answering.



(https://www.jdoodle.com/a/6aEz)

Comment: It is normally not a good idea to store code inside variables like this.

Comment: The shell parses syntax (pipes, quotes and escapes, etc) *before* expanding variables, so putting any of those in a variable doesn't work. Generally, use variables for storing data, functions for storing executable code. See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Regarding [I leave the link with the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105661/bash-problems-saving-pipe-awk-to-variable-and-then-executing-it-by-calling-the-v#comment134219118_76105661) - Don't provide information in comments, put it all in your question, and don't provide links or images, just plain text.